# Is LightGBM available for Mac M1?

Tags: python, pip, apple-m1, kaggle, lightgbm

My goal is to learn a [notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/josephchan524/bankchurnersclassifier-recall-97-accuracy-95). It has recall 97% while I am struggling with F1 Score 'Attrited Customer' 77.9%. The problem is the notebook uses LightGBM. I am unable to install LightGBM.

What I've tried:

1. `pip install lightgbm` -> it throws error `python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.`
2. Then, I did `pip install wheel` -> now it throws error `python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.`
3. Then, I did `pip install Cmake`, `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools`, `brew install libomp` -> the error persisted.

The full error

```
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [80 lines of output]
      INFO:root:running bdist_wheel
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      INFO:root:running build
      INFO:root:running build_py
      INFO:root:creating build
      INFO:root:creating build/lib
      INFO:root:creating build/lib/lightgbm
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of this writing, no official release of `lightgbm` (the Python package for LightGBM) supports the M1 Macs (which us ARM chips).

`osx-arm64` builds of `lightgbm` are supported by [the `lightgbm` conda-forge feedstock](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/lightgbm/files), so you can install `lightgbm` on an M1 Mac using `conda`.

```bash
conda install \
   --yes \
   -c conda-forge \
   'lightgbm>=3.3.3'
```

Progress towards officially supporting M1 Mac builds of LightGBM can be tracked in [microsoft/LightGBM#5269](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5269) and [microsoft/LightGBM#5328](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5328).

Comment: I am new with Python, 8 weeks in (to learn Data Analyst and Machine Learning) and my conda experience was not great (Mac M1 have python installed, homebrew has one for some reason, and then the one I installed myself. Somehow when I tried to install scikit learn, it brick my Python, so I spent my weekend to reinstall python). So I tried to install [the threadless version](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5574). For now, I will accept this as answer although I did not try it but apparently this has been resolved on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5328)

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer and for this explanation! You can subscribe to those linked LightGBM GitHub issues to be notified when a `pip install`-able version of the library that will work on M1 Macs is released.

Comment: This was helpful. Just for anyone curious, worked on a M3 Mac as well.